# Merge 365 XML Files to 1 File

Tags: xml, merge

I have 365 (more or less) different XML-FIles and I want to merge all the files to ONE XML File. My "root" for every file is "tageslesung", this will be the same, but inside the files can be different. How can I merge all the files automatically in one File?

Later I want to import one file into my SQL-Databse (-> TYPO3 CMS -> tx_news).

For example file 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tageslesungen datum="01.12.2013">
  <messe name="Erster Adventssonntag" tag="Sonntag" nr="1" kategorie="Advent" art="tageslesung">
    <lesung buch="JES" buchLang="Lesung aus dem Buch Jesaja" lesung="1" leseStelle="JES 2,1-5">
      <vers versNr="1" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Das Wort, das Jesaja, der Sohn des Amoz, in einer Vision über Juda und Jerusalem gehört hat.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="2" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Am Ende der Tage wird es geschehen: Der Berg mit dem Haus des Herrn steht fest gegründet als höchster der Berge; er überragt alle Hügel. Zu ihm strömen alle Völker.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="3" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Viele Nationen machen sich auf den Weg. Sie sagen: Kommt, wir ziehen hinauf zum Berg des Herrn und zum Haus des Gottes Jakobs. Er zeige uns seine Wege, auf seinen Pfaden wollen wir gehen. Denn von Zion kommt die Weisung des Herrn, aus Jerusalem sein Wort.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="4" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Er spricht Recht im Streit der Völker, er weist viele Nationen zurecht. Dann schmieden sie Pflugscharen aus ihren Schwertern und Winzermesser aus ihren Lanzen. Man zieht nicht mehr das Schwert, Volk gegen Volk, und übt nicht mehr für den Krieg.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="5" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Ihr vom Haus Jakob, kommt, wir wollen unsere Wege gehen im Licht des Herrn.]]></vers>
    </lesung>
    <lesung buch="RÖM" buchLang="Lesung aus dem Römerbrief" lesung="2" leseStelle="RÖM 13,11-14a">
      <vers versNr="11" kapitel="13"><![CDATA[Bedenkt die gegenwärtige Zeit: Die Stunde ist gekommen, aufzustehen vom Schlaf. Denn jetzt ist das Heil uns näher als zu der Zeit, da wir gläubig wurden.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="12" kapitel="13"><![CDATA[Die Nacht ist vorgerückt, der Tag ist nahe. Darum laßt uns ablegen die Werke der Finsternis und anlegen die Waffen des Lichts.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="13" kapitel="13"><![CDATA[Laßt uns ehrenhaft leben wie am Tag, ohne maßloses Essen und Trinken, ohne Unzucht und Ausschweifung, ohne Streit und Eifersucht.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="14" kapitel="13"><![CDATA[Legt (als neues Gewand) den Herrn Jesus Christus an, und sorgt nicht so für euren Leib, daß die Begierden erwachen.]]></vers>
    </lesung>
    <lesung buch="MT" buchLang="Aus dem Evangelium nach Matthäus" lesung="1" evangelium="true" leseStelle="MT 24,37-44">
      <vers versNr="37" kapitel="24"><![CDATA[Denn 
       wie es in den Tagen des Noach war, so wird es bei
       der Ankunft des Menschensohnes sein.]]></vers>
    </lesung>
  </messe>
</tageslesungen>
```

File 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tageslesungen datum="02.12.2013">
  <messe name="1. Montag im Advent" tag="Montag" nr="1" kategorie="Advent" art="tageslesung">
    <lesung buch="JES" buchLang="Lesung aus dem Buch Jesaja" lesung="1" leseStelle="JES 2,1-5">
      <vers versNr="1" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Das Wort, das Jesaja, der Sohn des Amoz, in einer Vision über Juda und Jerusalem gehört hat.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="2" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Am Ende der Tage wird es geschehen: Der Berg mit dem Haus des Herrn steht fest gegründet als höchster der Berge; er überragt alle Hügel. Zu ihm strömen alle Völker.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="3" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Viele Nationen machen sich auf den Weg. Sie sagen: Kommt, wir ziehen hinauf zum Berg des Herrn und zum Haus des Gottes Jakobs. Er zeige uns seine Wege, auf seinen Pfaden wollen wir gehen. Denn von Zion kommt die Weisung des Herrn, aus Jerusalem sein Wort.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="4" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Er spricht Recht im Streit der Völker, er weist viele Nationen zurecht. Dann schmieden sie Pflugscharen aus ihren Schwertern und Winzermesser aus ihren Lanzen. Man zieht nicht mehr das Schwert, Volk gegen Volk, und übt nicht mehr für den Krieg.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="5" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Ihr vom Haus Jakob, kommt, wir wollen unsere Wege gehen im Licht des Herrn.]]></vers>
    </lesung>
    <lesung buch="MT" buchLang="Aus dem Evangelium nach Matthäus" lesung="1" evangelium="true" leseStelle="MT 8,5-11">
      <vers versNr="5" kapitel="8"><![CDATA[Als er nach Kafarnaum kam, trat ein Hauptmann an ihn heran und bat ihn:]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="6" kapitel="8"><![CDATA[Herr, mein Diener liegt gelähmt zu Hause und hat große Schmerzen.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="7" kapitel="8"><![CDATA[Jesus sagte zu ihm: Ich will kommen und ihn gesund machen.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="8" kapitel="8"><![CDATA[Da antwortete der Hauptmann: Herr, ich bin es nicht wert, daß du mein Haus betrittst; sprich nur ein Wort, dann wird mein Diener gesund.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="9" kapitel="8"><![CDATA[Auch ich muß Befehlen gehorchen, und ich habe selber Soldaten unter mir; sage ich nun zu einem: Geh!, so geht er, und zu einem andern: Komm!, so kommt er, und zu meinem Diener: Tu das!, so tut er es.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="10" kapitel="8"><![CDATA[Jesus war erstaunt, als er das hörte, und sagte zu denen, die ihm nachfolgten: Amen, das sage ich euch: Einen solchen Glauben habe ich in Israel noch bei niemand gefunden.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="11" kapitel="8"><![CDATA[Ich sage euch: Viele werden von Osten und Westen kommen und mit Abraham, Isaak und Jakob im Himmelreich zu Tisch sitzen;]]></vers>
    </lesung>
  </messe>
  <messe art="heilige">
    <lesung buch="JAK" buchLang="Lesung aus dem Brief Jakobus" lesung="1" leseStelle="JAK 1,12-18">
      <vers versNr="12" kapitel="1"><![CDATA[Glücklich der Mann, der in der Versuchung standhält. Denn wenn er sich bewährt, wird er den Kranz des Lebens erhalten, der denen verheißen ist, die Gott lieben.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="13" kapitel="1"><![CDATA[Keiner, der in Versuchung gerät, soll sagen: Ich werde von Gott in Versuchung geführt. Denn Gott kann nicht in die Versuchung kommen, Böses zu tun, und er führt auch selbst niemand in Versuchung.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="14" kapitel="1"><![CDATA[Jeder wird von seiner eigenen Begierde, die ihn lockt und fängt, in Versuchung geführt.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="15" kapitel="1"><![CDATA[Wenn die Begierde dann schwanger geworden ist, bringt sie die Sünde zur Welt; ist die Sünde reif geworden, bringt sie den Tod hervor.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="16" kapitel="1"><![CDATA[Laßt euch nicht irreführen, meine geliebten Brüder;]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="17" kapitel="1"><![CDATA[jede gute Gabe und jedes vollkommene Geschenk kommt von oben, vom Vater der Gestirne, bei dem es keine Veränderung und keine Verfinsterung gibt.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="18" kapitel="1"><![CDATA[Aus freiem Willen hat er uns durch das Wort der Wahrheit geboren, damit wir gleichsam die Erstlingsfrucht seiner Schöpfung seien.]]></vers>
    </lesung>
    <lesung buch="JOH" buchLang="Aus dem Evangelium nach Johannes" lesung="0" evangelium="true" leseStelle="JOH 10,11-16">
      <vers versNr="11" kapitel="10"><![CDATA[Ich bin der gute Hirt. Der gute Hirt gibt sein Leben hin für die Schafe.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="12" kapitel="10"><![CDATA[Der bezahlte Knecht aber, der nicht Hirt ist und dem die Schafe nicht gehören, läßt die Schafe im Stich und flieht, wenn er den Wolf kommen sieht; und der Wolf reißt sie und jagt sie auseinander. Er flieht,]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="13" kapitel="10"><![CDATA[weil er nur ein bezahlter Knecht ist und ihm an den Schafen nichts liegt.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="14" kapitel="10"><![CDATA[Ich bin der gute Hirt; ich kenne die Meinen, und die Meinen kennen mich,]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="15" kapitel="10"><![CDATA[wie mich der Vater kennt und ich den Vater kenne; und ich gebe mein Leben hin für die Schafe.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="16" kapitel="10"><![CDATA[Ich habe noch andere Schafe, die nicht aus diesem Stall sind; auch sie muß ich führen, und sie werden auf meine Stimme hören; dann wird es nur eine Herde geben und einen Hirten.]]></vers>
    </lesung>
    <heiliger name="Heiliger Luzius" type="Bischof" maertyrer="true" id="2" />
  </messe>
</tageslesungen>
```

These files should be like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
      <tageslesungen datum="01.12.2013">
        <messe name="Erster Adventssonntag" tag="Sonntag" nr="1" kategorie="Advent" art="tageslesung">
          <lesung buch="JES" buchLang="Lesung aus dem Buch Jesaja" lesung="1" leseStelle="JES 2,1-5">
      <vers versNr="1" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Das Wort, das Jesaja, der Sohn des Amoz, in einer Vision über Juda und Jerusalem gehört hat.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="2" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Am Ende der Tage wird es geschehen: Der Berg mit dem Haus des Herrn steht fest gegründet als höchster der Berge; er überragt alle Hügel. Zu ihm strömen alle Völker.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="3" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Viele Nationen machen sich auf den Weg. Sie sagen: Kommt, wir ziehen hinauf zum Berg des Herrn und zum Haus des Gottes Jakobs. Er zeige uns seine Wege, auf seinen Pfaden wollen wir gehen. Denn von Zion kommt die Weisung des Herrn, aus Jerusalem sein Wort.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="4" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Er spricht Recht im Streit der Völker, er weist viele Nationen zurecht. Dann schmieden sie Pflugscharen aus ihren Schwertern und Winzermesser aus ihren Lanzen. Man zieht nicht mehr das Schwert, Volk gegen Volk, und übt nicht mehr für den Krieg.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="5" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Ihr vom Haus Jakob, kommt, wir wollen unsere Wege gehen im Licht des Herrn.]]></vers>
          </lesung>
        </messe>
      </tageslesungen>
      <tageslesungen datum="02.12.2013">
        <messe name="1. Montag im Advent" tag="Montag" nr="1" kategorie="Advent" art="tageslesung">
          <lesung buch="JES" buchLang="Lesung aus dem Buch Jesaja" lesung="1" leseStelle="JES 2,1-5">
      <vers versNr="1" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Das Wort, das Jesaja, der Sohn des Amoz, in einer Vision über Juda und Jerusalem gehört hat.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="2" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Am Ende der Tage wird es geschehen: Der Berg mit dem Haus des Herrn steht fest gegründet als höchster der Berge; er überragt alle Hügel. Zu ihm strömen alle Völker.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="3" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Viele Nationen machen sich auf den Weg. Sie sagen: Kommt, wir ziehen hinauf zum Berg des Herrn und zum Haus des Gottes Jakobs. Er zeige uns seine Wege, auf seinen Pfaden wollen wir gehen. Denn von Zion kommt die Weisung des Herrn, aus Jerusalem sein Wort.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="4" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Er spricht Recht im Streit der Völker, er weist viele Nationen zurecht. Dann schmieden sie Pflugscharen aus ihren Schwertern und Winzermesser aus ihren Lanzen. Man zieht nicht mehr das Schwert, Volk gegen Volk, und übt nicht mehr für den Krieg.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="5" kapitel="2"><![CDATA[Ihr vom Haus Jakob, kommt, wir wollen unsere Wege gehen im Licht des Herrn.]]></vers>
          </lesung>
        </messe>
  <messe art="heilige">
    <lesung buch="JAK" buchLang="Lesung aus dem Brief Jakobus" lesung="1" leseStelle="JAK 1,12-18">
      <vers versNr="12" kapitel="1"><![CDATA[Glücklich der Mann, der in der Versuchung standhält. Denn wenn er sich bewährt, wird er den Kranz des Lebens erhalten, der denen verheißen ist, die Gott lieben.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="13" kapitel="1"><![CDATA[Keiner, der in Versuchung gerät, soll sagen: Ich werde von Gott in Versuchung geführt. Denn Gott kann nicht in die Versuchung kommen, Böses zu tun, und er führt auch selbst niemand in Versuchung.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="14" kapitel="1"><![CDATA[Jeder wird von seiner eigenen Begierde, die ihn lockt und fängt, in Versuchung geführt.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="15" kapitel="1"><![CDATA[Wenn die Begierde dann schwanger geworden ist, bringt sie die Sünde zur Welt; ist die Sünde reif geworden, bringt sie den Tod hervor.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="16" kapitel="1"><![CDATA[Laßt euch nicht irreführen, meine geliebten Brüder;]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="17" kapitel="1"><![CDATA[jede gute Gabe und jedes vollkommene Geschenk kommt von oben, vom Vater der Gestirne, bei dem es keine Veränderung und keine Verfinsterung gibt.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="18" kapitel="1"><![CDATA[Aus freiem Willen hat er uns durch das Wort der Wahrheit geboren, damit wir gleichsam die Erstlingsfrucht seiner Schöpfung seien.]]></vers>
    </lesung>
    <lesung buch="JOH" buchLang="Aus dem Evangelium nach Johannes" lesung="0" evangelium="true" leseStelle="JOH 10,11-16">
      <vers versNr="11" kapitel="10"><![CDATA[Ich bin der gute Hirt. Der gute Hirt gibt sein Leben hin für die Schafe.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="12" kapitel="10"><![CDATA[Der bezahlte Knecht aber, der nicht Hirt ist und dem die Schafe nicht gehören, läßt die Schafe im Stich und flieht, wenn er den Wolf kommen sieht; und der Wolf reißt sie und jagt sie auseinander. Er flieht,]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="13" kapitel="10"><![CDATA[weil er nur ein bezahlter Knecht ist und ihm an den Schafen nichts liegt.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="14" kapitel="10"><![CDATA[Ich bin der gute Hirt; ich kenne die Meinen, und die Meinen kennen mich,]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="15" kapitel="10"><![CDATA[wie mich der Vater kennt und ich den Vater kenne; und ich gebe mein Leben hin für die Schafe.]]></vers>
      <vers versNr="16" kapitel="10"><![CDATA[Ich habe noch andere Schafe, die nicht aus diesem Stall sind; auch sie muß ich führen, und sie werden auf meine Stimme hören; dann wird es nur eine Herde geben und einen Hirten.]]></vers>
    </lesung>
    <heiliger name="Heiliger Luzius" type="Bischof" maertyrer="true" id="2" />
  </messe>
      </tageslesungen>
    </root>
```

Comment: What programming/scripting/transformation language do you plan on using?

Comment: What have you tried? What tools/languages do you want to use? Looks like a simple concatenation and filtering out the `<?xml>` headers would serve.

Comment: Later I want to import one file into my SQL-Databse (-> TYPO3 CMS -> tx_news). I don't want to import 365 files. Another point is, to edit the whole XML-file at once (copy & paste : insert <br> and suff)

I also think, that I can crop the part "tageslesung" from every file into a new one and wrap these with an new XML-Tag (e.g. root).